# does vector exist in matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

how can I check to see if vector exists inside a matrix. The vector will be of size 2. I have an approach but I would like something vectorized/faster.

```
dim(m)
[1] 30  2

x = c(1, -2)

for(j in 1:nrow(m)){
    if ( isTRUE(as.vector(x[1]) == as.vector(m[j,1])) && as.vector(x[2] == as.vector(m[j,2]) )) { 
print(TRUE) 
  }
}
```

note, *x=c(1, -2)* is not the same as *-2, 1* in the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
m<-matrix(rnorm(60),30)
x<-m[8,]
m[9,]<-c(x[2],x[1]) # to prove 1,-2 not same -2,1

apply(m,1,function(n,x) all(n==x),x=x)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[24] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

if you need just one T/F use any() you

```
any(apply(m,1,function(n,x) all(n==x),x=x))
[1] TRUE
```

if run this code with akrun's data

```
x <- c(1, -2)
set.seed(24)
m <- matrix(sample(c(1,-2,3,4), 30*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=2)

any(apply(m,1,function(n,x) all(n==x),x=x))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

If we are comparing the rows of the `matrix` ('m') with 'x' having the same length as the number of columns of 'm', we can replicate 'x' (`x[col(m)]`) to make the lengths same, compare (`!=`), get the `rowSums`.  If the sum is 0 for a particular row, it means that all the values in the `vector` matches that row of 'm'.  Negate (`!`) to convert `0` to `TRUE` and all other values as `FALSE`.

```
indx1 <- !rowSums(m!=x[col(m)])
```

Or if we need a solution using `apply`, we can use `identical`

```
indx2 <- apply(m, 1, identical, y=x)
identical(indx1, indx2)
#[1] TRUE
```

If this to find only a single `TRUE/FALSE`, we can wrap `any` to 'indx1' or 'indx2'.

#### data

```
x <- c(1, -2)
set.seed(24)
m <- matrix(sample(c(1,-2,3,4), 30*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=2)
```